# Creating set from nested list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, set

```
marksheet = [['harry',87], ['bob', 76], ['bucky', 98]]

print(set([marks for name, marks in marksheet]))

output: {98, 76, 87}
```

Can someone please explain how this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're iterating `name, marks` over `marksheet`. So you're extracting two values and storing them as `name`, which you ignore, and `marks`, which you create a list from. That list you just create is passed to `set`, which creates a set. You can break the code down step by step:

```
marksheet = [['harry',87], ['bob', 76], ['bucky', 98]]
In [40]: marksheet                                                                                                           
Out[40]: [['harry', 87], ['bob', 76], ['bucky', 98]]

In [41]: l = [marks for name, marks in marksheet]                                                                            

In [42]: l                                                                                                                   
Out[42]: [87, 76, 98]
```

You can also surround the values you're extracting in parentheses to help make it more clear:

```
In [43]: l = [marks for (name, marks) in marksheet]                                                                          

In [44]: l                                                                                                                   
Out[44]: [87, 76, 98]
```

Some people use `_` to denote the returned value is ignored:

```
In [45]: l = [marks for (_, marks) in marksheet]                                                                             

In [46]: l                                                                                                                   
Out[46]: [87, 76, 98]
```

The above is an example of list comprehension. This is equivalent to:

```
In [47]: l=[]                                                                                                                

In [48]: for (name, marks) in marksheet: 
    ...:     l.append(marks) 
    ...:                                                                                                                     

In [49]: l                                                                                                                   
Out[49]: [87, 76, 98]
```

From there you are simply passing the list to `set`, which can take an iterable. In this case, the list you just created is the iterable:

```
In [50]: set(l)                                                                                                              
Out[50]: {76, 87, 98}
```